# how to reconnect to already saved network?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-11

i am able to save and connect to wifi using bellow code

```
final ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion>();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
        .setSsid("MyiPhone")
        .setWpa2Passphrase("myIphone123@#")
        .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
        .build();

final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion1 =
        new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setSsid("iPhone")
                .setWpa2Passphrase("iphone123@#")
                .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
                .build();

suggestionsList.add(suggestion);
suggestionsList.add(suggestion1);

final int status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);

if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Internet...");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Suggestion success...");

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST, suggestionsList);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 5000);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<Integer> results = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_RESULT_LIST);
    Log.e(TAG, " * * * length " + results.size());
    for(int res : results) {
        //first time it prints ADD_WIFI_RESULT_SUCCESS and next time onwards ADD_WIFI_RESULT_ALREADY_EXISTS
        Log.e(TAG, " * * * res " + res);
    }
}
```

I want to reconnect to the saved network but unable to find a way to achieve it, is there a way to re connect to the saved network in android11?